# Visual atrifacts when running Selenium tests in chrome on mac

Tags: macos, selenium-webdriver

I've found that when I run Selenium tests on my mac in chrome browser, the site is opened with some strange visual artifacts - only borders of elements appear and no text. [image: Screenshot here]

I've tried java and python to run selenium, chrome driver 2.37-2.40. Latest stable chrome browser version, Default MacOS graphic driver and Nvidia Web graphic driver. Nothing helped.

Can you suggest, how to solve it?

Example of code:

```html
import org.openqa.selenium.*;
import org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        WebDriver driver = new ChromeDriver();
        driver.get("https://google.com");
        System.out.println("Done");
    }
}
```

Comment: Try without using Incognito mode. Do You get same behaviour with normal mode?

Comment: The same without incognito mode.

Comment: Please provide example code

Comment: I've updated the question.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I could solve it by adding `--disable-gpu` chrome option. But it's rather workaround and I still could not figure out why these artifacts appear.